# Modify list of strings to only have max n-length strings (use of Linq)

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

Suppose we have a list of strings like below:

```cs
List<string> myList = new List<string>(){"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

There are some items with the length of more than 3.

By the help of Linq I want to divide them into new items in the list, so the new list will have these items:

```cs
{"one", "two", "thr", "ee", "fou", "r"};
```

Don't ask me why Linq. I am a Linq fan and don't like unLinq code :D

Comment: Trivial. What have *you* tried at the very first place?

Comment: You'll likely be much better of with non-LINQ code that you should have, but for some reason did not include in the post... What are your requirements for "simply with LINQ" -(i.e. single statement)?

Comment: I can do it by creating new list and a foreach loop. but my question was how to do it by Linq.

Comment: How do you handle values in your list having less than 3 characters?

Comment: I am practicing the Linq code, and I was curious how it could be done in Linq. Otherwise doing it by a loop will be easy. So I emphesize on Linq.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff divide them into two or more items in the list if they are more than 3-length and leave them untouched if they are less than 3-length.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Sorry, I editet it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Sorry, I had to clearly mention that I need Linq code.

Comment: I get that this is for fun, but please don't ever use LINQ for something like this in the real world. It's not what it's for, so it would be terribly inefficient compared to other techniques.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For real code basic `for` would likely be better (i.e. as shown in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364197/477420).

If you really need LINQ split string into 3-letter chunks and than merge all with `SelectMany`:

```
var list = new[]{"", "a", "abc","dee","eff","aa","rewqs"};
var result = list
  .Select( 
    s => 
      Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length / 3 + 
             (s.Length == 0 || (s.Length % 3 > 0) ? 1 : 0))
      .Select(i => s.Substring(
         i * 3,
         Math.Min(s.Length - i * 3, 3))))
  .SelectMany(x=>x);
```

`Range` creates enumerable for all segments of the string (which is either length/3 if all pieces are exactly 3 characters, or one more if last one is shorter than 3 character).

`.Select(i => s.Substring...` splits string into chunks of 3 or less characters (need to carefully adjust length to avoid index out of range error)

`.SelectMany` combines list of list of 3 character segments into flat list of 3 character segments.

---

Note: This LINQ code should be used for entertainment/learning purposes. If you must use similar LINQ solution in production code at least convert splitting of string into more readable helper function.

Comment: That's beautiful and horrible at the same time.

Comment: Thats fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff, Of course it is not even close to best practice, but I believe it can help to challenge in Linq.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff completely agree with "horrible" part - I've inlined some comments about it in the post. OP needed a LINQ solution so I've added one that is at least explainable (also using `"test".GroupBy((c,i)=> i/3)` to split string into 3 character segments would be even more insane).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you can do that with Linq. Here is a non-linq solution:

```
for (int x = 0; x < myList.Count; x++)
{
    if (myList[x].Length > 3)
    {
        var oldString = myList[x];
        myList[x] = oldString.Substring(0, 3);
        myList.Insert(x + 1, oldString.Substring(3));
    }
}
```

Edit: Apparently you can do that with Linq. Well, this is a non-linq solution anyways...

Comment: just because you CAN doesn't mean you SHOULD  =)

Answer (score 4):

I see I'm late while was preparing my answer, which is basically the same as the accepted, but I'm posting it mainly to present the query syntax solution, which in this case IMO is more readable

```
var result =
    (from s in myList
     from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (s.Length - 1) / 3)
     let start = i * 3
     let length = Math.Min(3, s.Length - start)
     select s.Substring(start, length))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Good alternative syntax. BTW, you have the same bug I've just fixed in my post - empty strings are removed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you, I didn't catch that case, fixed.